# Issue sending pdf, excel, html, docx by send_from_directory & send_file in Flask server

Tags: flask

Environment: Flask 1.1.0

I'm experiencing an issue with file corruption when sending files from a Flask server. My server is currently set up to store files under a path specified by UPLOAD_FOLDER in each project. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
@file_ns.route('/download')
class downloadFile(Resource):
    @file_ns.expect(show_file)
    @jwt_required() 
    def post(self):
        # [Code truncated for brevity]
        try:
            return send_from_directory(server_path, filename, as_attachment=True)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            abort(404)
```

When I upload a PDF file (e.g., from this [link](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.publhealth.27.021405.102100)), it appears fine on the server. However, problems arise when I attempt to download the file: it opens as blank in the PDF viewer.

Inspecting the downloaded file with Vim reveals that the content is not lost - it just seems unreadable or incorrectly encoded. Here is a sample of the Vim output:

```
%PDF-1.4 
   2 %����
   3 2 0 obj
   ...
   31 <</Type/XObject/Resour
```

I suspect the issue lies in my send_from_directory function usage or the way I'm encoding/decoding the file. Could someone help me figure out why the files are corrupt when sent from the Flask server?

I've attempted several strategies to resolve this issue, including using the send_file function with an explicitly defined mimetype. I've also tried opening the file in byte mode prior to sending it, and passing the read file into the function. Unfortunately, these approaches have not been successful so far.

Comment: Can you include the route that performs the file upload/save to disk? Have you looked at the files in your web server directory? Are they corrupted at that point?

Comment: @barryodev , I checked it on the vs-code remote, which is all good on the server.